# Can't receive packages through wifi

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, dns, internet

In my Linux Mint 18 installation I can connect to the WiFi just fine however the Internet connection stops working nevertheless... It will take ages trying to look up the respective web address I typed in (e.g google.com) and finally throws an unknown host error.

I tried reconnecting to the WiFi network and rebooting the PC but that didn't help (the problem either persisted or came back shortly after).

My research pointed me to checking my DNS connection (if you can call it that) so I tried to ping a DNS server with

```
ping 198.41.0.4 -c 5
```

Which takes some time and then spits out the following

```
5 packages transmitted, 0 received, 100% package loss, time 4031ms
```

I would interpret that as somehow the Internet traffic to my computer is blocked or corrupted somewhere as it seems that I can send data just fine...

Does somebody have an idea what the cause of this problem might be?

EDIT:
I should stress that this problem occurs periodically... The internet works just fine for some time and then it simply stops working with the above described symptoms. After waiting a while it starts working again...
This does also only seem to happen in my room and nowhere else in the house. However I have a working wifi connection with my phone all the time

EDIT 2:
`ip route` outputs

```
default via 192.168.178.1 dev wlo1  proto static  metric 600 
192.168.178.0/24 dev wlo1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.178.36  metric 600
```

and `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` outputs

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    DeviceName: Realtek Sanji2 RTL8723BE b/g/n 1x1 + BT 4 LE PCIe+USB M.2
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:81c1]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
```

However this output is gathered now that the internet connection is currently working, but I don't know if that is important for this one...

EDIT 3:
No this question is no duplicate of the linked one because I have the `rtl8723b2` module installed!
However there is a **solution to this problem** right [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396495/no-internet-acess-through-wifi).

Comment: I'll edit my question with the respective information...

Comment: I'm actually unsure whether I have this thing already installed or not... At least I already do have the exact same configuration file as described in the post and I seem to have the module `rtl8723be` as `modprobe rtl8723be` won't throw any erros...

Comment: I haven't noticed that the Internet has stopped working, and I would worry very much if Mint and your WiFi adapter could bring it down.